# Date Formatting/Error handling trouble in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have an iOS app that receives data via webservice calls. Everything was working then, without warning, the app began to crash. I have traced it down to a line that formats date-time values. The webservice originally returned date values as:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssz
```

then, without warning the date format changed to:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
```

and an exception resulted. I have corrected the problem, however, the web service provides data from thousands of stations around the nation that report time sensitive data. Therefore, I can't guarantee that the old date format isn't still returned from some web service calls.

Coming from a C# and Java background, my normal approach to this issue would be a try/catch block. However, Objective-C is a different animal when it comes to exception handling. I'm not sure how to handle the different date formats. Here is my current code to do the date-time formatting

```
-(NSString*)stringDateFormatter:(NSString*)dateToFormat{
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    //[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssz"];
    [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    NSDate *newDateValue = [df dateFromString:dateToFormat];

    [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString *retValue = [df stringFromDate:newDateValue];

    return retValue;
}
```

What might be a best practice in hadling the two different date-time formats? Thanks! V

Comment: By the time you get an exception you're too far down the road, and, besides, exceptions in Objective-C don't work all that well.  Just test the result of dateFromString for nil, or check the incoming string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you might get a date string in one of two different formats then try one first. If you get a `nil` result, try the other format.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *newDateValue = [df dateFromString:dateToFormat];
if (!newDateValue) {
    [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssz"];
    newDateValue = [df dateFromString:dateToFormat];
}
```

BTW - there is no need to set the timezone to the local timezone. That is already the default.

Comment: Or somehow examine the input string to see which format you have.